# AngularJS with HTML5mode(true) on IIS and <default document>

Tags: .net, angularjs, html, iis, web

I have a simple app running on IIS 8.0 (arvixe hosting) that uses AngularJS for the SPA framework. I turned on html5mode and linked the  tag to index.html (the root file), I've also set this file as the  in the web.config. I know you have to do server-side rewrites which I have.

What I want to achieve is the following:

User enters 'domain.com' and the site load up domain.com/home. Of course under the URL is actually domain.com/index.html/home but html5mode handles that with the rewrites.

Here is the app.config and this is fine.

```
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/forum', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/forum.html',
        controller: 'ForumController'
    })
    .when('/rebellinks', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/rebellinks.html',
        controller: 'RebelLinksController'
    })
    .when('/events', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
        controller: 'EventsController'
    })
    .when('/oldnews', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/oldnews.html',
        controller: 'OldNewsController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

//use HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   }]);
```

Web.Config file for IIS:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />       
        <!--<rule name="jsRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".js" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>-->

        <rule name="SRBShome" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularJS" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>        
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="home.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

What this does is loads domain.com/home when the user visits the site but the .js files are transferred as  I added a special rule in the rewrite to prevent them from rewriting but I think my pattern on the SRBShome rule needs to be adjusted to work correctly.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resolved it with changing the rewrite rules below. This allows index.html to be loaded on IIS. For some reason  in web.config doesn't work for this setting. So now when a user requests domain.com the rewrite passes '/index.html' then AngularJS' html5Mode kicks in and cleans up the URLs and removes the hashbang.

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />        
        <rule name="SRBShome" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.+)$" negate="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URL}" pattern="^(.+)$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
          <!--<match url="^.com" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />-->
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularJS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>        
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: This works great when your backend (e.g. web api) is deployed somewhere else.